# Find EyeMap of an image using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, eye-detection

I tried coding for `EyeMapC` but couldn't get expected output.

> EyeMapC = 1/3(Cb<sup>2</sup> + Cr'<sup>2</sup> + Cb/Cr)

where `Cr' = 255 - Cr`

Here's my code

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img/file.jpg')
EyeMap = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
y,Cr,Cb = cv2.split(EyeMap)
Q = np.square(Cb) #,dtype=np.float64)
Cr_bar = (255-Cr)
R = np.square(Cr_bar) #,dtype=np.float64)
G = Cb/Cr
EyeC = (Q/3+R/3+G/3)
#EyeC = np.mod(EyeC,255)

cv2.imshow('EyeC',EyeC)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Cb<sup>2</sup> and Cr'<sup>2</sup> have to be normalized between [0,255] before putting in formula or the final `EyeC` value needs to be normalized ?

Original Image: [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J1pl.jpg)

Output:  [Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYXXU.jpg)

Comment: *"...but couldn't get expected output."*  Please explain this. What did you expect, and what did you get?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Chk the original image and output image